# trigger gmail inbox refresh with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail

I am trying to simulate the click on the refresh button above the inbox.
This is my current (not working) script:

```
var $elem = $('div.T-I.J-J5-Ji.nu.T-I-ax7.L3'); //getting the "refresh" button
if ($elem.length > 0) {
      var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
      });

    $elem[0].dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

I also tried to use `trigger('click')` and `click()` on the query object.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some time ago. For some reason, it requires the button to be focused and the event ocurrs ONLY after a keydown|mousedow AND then keyup|mouseup is executed. Saddly, using click() or any other JQuery event trigger doesn't work.

My solution using pure JS:

```
function refreshDomNow() {
    var refreshButtons = $( 'div.T-I.J-J5-Ji.nu.T-I-ax7.L3' ),
        buttonsFounds = refreshButtons.length,
        visibleButton = 0,
        refreshed = false;

    if ( buttonsFounds > 0 ) {              // There should be at least one of these buttons
        for ( var i = 0; i < buttonsFounds; i++ ) {
            var currentButton = $(refreshButtons[i]);
            if ( currentButton.is(':visible') ) {
                var rButton = $(rButtonClass)[i];
                visibleButton++;

                //Trigger mouse down event
                var mouseDown = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                mouseDown.initEvent( 'mousedown', true, false );
                rButton.dispatchEvent(mouseDown);

                //Trigger mouse up event
                var mouseUp = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                mouseUp.initEvent( 'mouseup', true, false );
                rButton.dispatchEvent(mouseUp);     // This opens the composer

                refreshed = true;
            }   // End of IF currentButton.is(':visible')
        }       // End of FOR loop
    }           // End of IF buttonsFounds > 0

    return refreshed;
}               // End of refreshDomNow();
```

And even though this works, I'm not happy with it. Mainly because the refresh button is not visible when you are reading a mail thread. I'm looking for one step ahead: I want to know HOW to trigger the function that is attached to the refresh button (and yes, trigger() does not work) without the need of clicking it.

Any ideas? thoughts?

Comment: Hi Alberto, I think refreshing when you are reading an email does not make sense, does it?

Comment: It makes if you need the labels to update (I'm modifying the labels using Google API) or you need it to load any mail that has arrived to the inbox but hasn't been populated into the thread.